# Реально ли отправить за раз 1000 запросов retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit

У меня есть желание протестировать выданное мне апи. Я хочу за один раз отправить 1000 запросов к апи на получение информации. Тип запроса - GET. Я видел что вроде как можно использовать dispatcher или timer но не очень понял как именно. Или же то что я хочу сделать невозможно или лучше не тратить зря время? Может есть какой-то рабочий способ кроме тупого нажатия на кнопку, хотя даже если очень быстро нажимать кнопку все-равно 1000 запросов за раз точно не отправить? Так же не хотелось бы поймать переполнение стека :)

Comment: Непонятна цель теста - что тестируем - справится ли сервер с 1000 запросами? Не думаю, что телефон сможет положить его на лопатки))) Для таких тестов лучше поискать тестирующий сервис в сети.

Comment: да @woesss, вы угадали))) но цель не сервер положить на лопатки а программу, пытаться положить сервер телефоном, это тоже самое что идти на таран камаза сидя на велосипеде, меня интересует возможное создание затыка в программе, чтобы логика не выдержала и сломалась, я не сомневаюсь что человек писавший апи умен, но это задание дал именно он, а так как у меня только одна учетка для тестирование апи я хочу как-то реализовать много запросов за раз

Comment: Не знаю каким чудом может возникнуть такой затык когда вы даже искусственно не знаете как такое сотворить))) Можно тупо в цикле послать сколько угодно запросов, но они по-любому будут не 
 все 1000 одновременные и как раз таки переполнение стека и памяти - это то что вы кучей запросов можете протестировать, кроме тупления интерфейса.

Comment: значит остается только сервис найти какой-то, но все-равно наверное затея так себе :)

Comment: А почему бы не написать очень много запросов в разных потоках?)))
Как раз и телефон можно протестить на  мощность)

Comment: Ну... Самый простой способ - пустить цикл и в цикле запустить запрос. Далее либо сервак упадёт или приложение зависнет. Тогда можно быть выяснять что именно сломалось и где и как чинить. Вроде бы вся проверка займёт пару минут.